# Applying impulse to velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision, software

I'm writing physics engine and so far got some good results but stuck on 1 task i would like to ask. Got some mistake in my formula.

Here is a question:Imagine 1 square colliding into another one. both are 2d squares and have equal masses.

we know that post velocity of body A can be found by following expression

```
va2 = va1 + j n / ma , where n is normal of the edge upon which 1 body collide another
```

Description of problem: Imagine first square have velocity expressed by (0,150) pixels per 1/60 sec.other one have speed (0,0).

i have found the impules **J**. Now all we need is just apply this impulse using the formula above.

```
so va2.x = va1.x + jn/ma
   va2.y = va1.y + jn/ma
```

the **jn/ma**  is a scalar value so we will get va2.x != 0 which is incorrect because i got result like this

```
  va2.y=150 - 150  
  va2.x=0-150 = -150
```

now imagine that before collision the fisrt body had (0,150) pixels per 1/60 sec and after (150,0). this is pretty unrealistic, i have searched the source code in box2d but it calculates the post velocity in exact this way.

Any help or advice appreciated. Hope I describe the problem clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I have found mistake in my calculatuion.

First

j =    −(1 + e) vab1 · n

j/= 1⁄ma + 1⁄mb + (rap × n)2 ⁄ Ia + (rbp × n)2 ⁄ Ib

is how we calculate the impulse. taken from here http://myphysicslab.com/collision.html.
the expression (rap × n) is a cross product of vectros, i calcualted it as dot product.

and the expression **jn** is NOT a scalar value. it is vector..)

it was just a lack of attention )

Comment: Yes, $j$ is a scalar impulse value and $\bf n$ is a vector normal direction. Together they create a momentum exchange vector.